# I need a DropDown value that is linked to another page

Tags: asp.net

I have a DropDown List where I have brought the values from my Database using code-behind.

I have added a new value after reading data from source, called ".. Add new skill".

Now when user clicks on that item I need a small page (or rather a new page) to open to add the skills that are not mentioned in the DropDownList.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=KKSTech;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT SkillName, SkillID FROM Skills", myConn);
    myConn.Open();
    SqlDataReader myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader();

    //Set up the data binding.
    DropDownList1.DataSource = myReader;
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "SKillName";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "SkillID";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();

    //Close the connection.
    myConn.Close();
    myReader.Close();

    //Add the item at the first position.
    DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "..Add New Skill");
}
```

This is my code-behind file.. How do I link that now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `AutoPostBack` to true. That way when the user changes an option, it will automatically post the page to the server.

Handle this SelectedIndexChanged event, and redirect to your add page there.

- Take your user to a add page.
- Add the details to the database.
- Bring the user back to this page.
- List will be reloaded from database, and you till get your value.

No special linking is required.

Comment: And how'd I add link during binding to the item??
Its admin who is adding skills of an employee, so when he sees there is no skill in the list, he selects this item 'add new' then he adds the new skill..

Answer (score 1):

Add a `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler to that `dropdown` like this

```
void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(ddl.SelectedIndex == 0)
        Response.Redirect("Add_New_Skill.aspx");
    }
```

If you want position of "...Add new skill" to be at last of the list

Use this

```
ddl.Items.Insert(ddl.Items.Count, "...Add New Skill");
```

Now to redirect to another page you should do this

```
void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ddl.SelectedIndex == ddl.Items.Count-1)
       Response.Redirect("Add_New_Skill.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Hello.. I tried that its a good idea.. But the problem is the value "..Add new skill" is having value 0, so when I run it, it redirects automatically to different page. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Why not put 'Add new skill' to the end? That way, the user will scan the list too, to check if it is there?

Comment: Yes thats my question.. How'd I add it in the end?

Comment: @Girish: Add **-select-**  at value -1

Comment: @Girish Use `ddl.Items.Insert(ddl.Items.Count-1, "..Add New Skill");`

Comment: @Girish: Add Item as **--SELECT--**  into your dropdownlist having value as -1 and so at 0 will your Add new skill

Comment: @yogi I used this DropDownList1.Items.Insert(DropDownList1.Items.Count , "..Add New Skill"); 
And it worked.. :) Thanks..

Comment: I shouldn't used Count-1, because it comes one up from last item..
To end up in the end I need to use "ddl.Items.Count, "Add New"

Comment: **+1**  for adding item at last position

Comment: @satindersingh How'd I link that item to another page? I followed what Phist had said, but it is not working.. :(

Comment: @Girish: Have you set Autopostback= "true" for you dropdownlist ?

Comment: @satindersingh thanks.. I hadn't . :) Now I did.. It is kinda posting back to server but not transferring to the page I mentioned.. :(

Answer (score 1):

You should use the SelectedIndexChanged event and SelectedValue property:

```
   void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(String.Compare(ddl.SelectedValue,"..Add New Skill",true)==0)
       Response.Redirect("Add_New_Skill.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Try use this instead:    
 `void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {  var value=System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)sender).Text;             if(String.Compare(value,"..Add New Skill",true)==0) 
Response.Redirect("Add_New_Skill.aspx"); } `

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            bindDropdownlist()
        }
    }
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string getvalue = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
        if (getvalue == "..Add New Skill")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.apsx");
        }
    }

  public void bindDropdownlist()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter("select coloumn1,colum2 from table", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dap.Fill(ds);
        DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "coloumn1";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "colum2 ";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "..Add New Skill");
    }
}
```

---

```
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
```